# JQuery DataTables - How to apply functions to all rows (not just the first 10 shown)

Tags: jquery, function, datatables

I am using the JQuery DataTables plugin for displaying large sets of data. One thing I am trying to do is shorten the 'details' column (sometimes they are around 1000 characters) to a small string so that the rows are all fairly the same height and easier to read. Then when a user clicks on the small string, it opens a dialog and displays the full details.

It works great, but only on the first 10 rows (since those are all that is shown by default).  Once I expand the table to display the rest of the rows, the function doesnt seem to be applied to those newly shown rows. Is there a call or option in dataTables that will apply the function everytime the row set being shown is changed?

Here is the dataTables call:

```
    $('#dataTable').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "fnInitComplete": function(){
        $('.display_results').show();
        $('.def').click(function(){
            var msg = $(this).next().text();
            $('.messages').messageBox();//Custom Dialog box call

        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out!
http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks
use 'fnDrawCallback'

```
    $('#dataTable').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "fnInitComplete": function(){
        $('.display_results').show();
    },
    "fnDrawCallback": function() {
        $('.def').click(function(){
            var msg = $(this).next().text();
            $('.messages').messageBox()//Custom Dialog
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i was stuck on same issue from 1 day.

Comment: but i have another issue the events on 2nd page are not working first time when i navigate page. to make them work i come back to first page and then navigate to 2nd page then it works. any thing to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use "fnDrawCallback" property while declaring the "DataTable" as we have used in our recent project.

Answer (score 0):

Its best to use live events for this kind of thing: http://datatables.net/faqs#events . Ideally the messageBox plug-in could be modified to use live events.

Allan

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you should had done is:

```
$(".def").live('click', function() {
//your code here
});
```

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated, you should use `.on()` instead.